# document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow.myFrameFunction() won't work in Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

It works in Firefox 20.0.1 and IE 10.0.9200.16442, but both input elements won't work in Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Chrome console showed this:

Uncaught TypeError: Property 'say' of object [object global] is not a function

========================main.html=======================

```
function say() { 
    alert("parent.html------>I'm at parent.html"); 
} 

function callChild() 
{ 
    var ifrm = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    ifrm.contentWindow.say();
} 

< input type=button value="invoke say() in the child.html" onclick="callChild()" /> 

< iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame" src="child.html" />
```

========================child.html=======================

```
function say() 
{
    alert("child.html--->I'm at child.html"); 
} 

function callParent() {
    window.parent.say();
}

< input type=button value="invoke function say() in the parent.html" onclick="callParent()" />
```

Comment: are you sure FF and IE are working correct? maybe chrome is right! say() is not a function for that object of contentWindow<- global in other words you can not use jquery like typing without prototyping its object where you call it on.

Answer (score 0):

my prototype bla bla was wrong, but see the difference when called from your iframe

```
function callParent() {
    console.log(window.say); //childs.say function
    console.log(top.say); //parents.say function
    console.log(self.say, this.parent.say); //more fun!
    //window.parent.say();
}
```

Comment: The window.say showed the function code, while top.say and this.parent.say is undefined. Also, chrome prompted that Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL ......  Domains, protocols and ports must match.